# INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK when trying to run on an Gingerbread device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-2.3-gingerbread

I read some stuff on the net about this problem. But the solution presented did not solve my problem.

I've a Android device with enabled usb debugging and Android 2.3.6 running on it. I downloaded Android Studio and downloaded the SDK API 10 (Android Version 2.3.3) and I added the following lines to my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

I cleaned and rebuilt the project. However, I'm still getting the error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I downloaded Android Studio and downloaded the SDK API 10 (Android
>   Version 2.3.3) and I added the following lines to my
>   AndroidManifest.xml:

you have to update your `build.gradle` file *(module build.gradle)*. Those values in the `AndroidManifest` are ignored

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 10
}
```

also you can remove `targetSdkVersion`, since they are the same value. If you leave it unset, android will pick up automatically the value of the `minSdkVersion`

Comment: Now I get the error `Gradle DSL method not found: 'defaultConfig()'`

Comment: @toom: The `defaultConfig` closure should already have existed. You should not need to have created one. Edit your existing `defaultConfig` and the `minSdkVersion` property in it.

Comment: @Blackbelt: "If you leave it unset, android will pick up automatically the value of the minSdkVersion" -- are you sure about that?

Comment: In my `build.gradle` is no `defaultConfig ` closure. I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0.

Comment: @CommonsWare, it is in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Comment: @toom can you update the question with the content of build.gradle ?

Comment: @toom: [Here is a sample `build.gradle` file](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/EmPubLite-AndroidStudio/T3-Manifest/EmPubLite/app/build.gradle) for an `app/` module that shows where `defaultConfig` and `minSdkVersion` go.

Comment: @Blackbelt: Interesting. I am pretty sure it used to default to 1. Wonder when they changed it. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Okay, there exist actually two `build.gradle` files. The other one did work. Thanks